# Sending SSL Certificates with ActiveXObject WinHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ssl, asp-classic, certificate, httprequest

I need to send a SOAP envelope to a URL but the connection requires certification. Trying to submit without returns:

```
WinHttp.WinHttpRequest error '80072f0c'

A certificate is required to complete client authentication
```

I've little experience of such certification and my googling is not yielding many helpful results. We run Javascript on .ASP so PHP CURL is not possible unfortunately.

We have all the certificate files required to use the API behind the URL. I believe I may have to install the certificates to my local machine but my attempts to do so and call from it have not worked.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think adding the certificate to the Server Certificates for the site in IIS might be what I'm after, but for some reason the certificate isn't appearing in the drop-down nor is it showing up in the Microsoft Management Console Certificates snap-in. Even when I explicitly state the location to export it to.